# Why the code works only for first three iterations?

Tags: python

Will you please help why the code gives correct output for minimal and maximum  only for first three iterations?

My output for first three iterations works correctly. minimal and maximum variables get latched to those values and don't update as per new inputs.
The remaining calculations (sum,count and average) work fine.

```
[enter image description here][1]
count= 0
sum=0
average=0
minimal=None
maximum=None
while True:
    number=raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        if (number=='done'):
            break
        else:
            count=count+1
            sum=sum+float(number)
            if minimal==None:
                minimal=float(number)
                maximum=float(number)
            else:
                minimal=min(number,minimal)
                maximum=max(number,maximum)
                print maximum
                print minimal
            average=sum/count
            #print ("Calc done")
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
print("Count: %d, Sum=%d and Average=%d" %(count,sum,average))
print("smallest number is %d" %minimal)
print("largest number is %0.2f" %float(maximum))
```

Comment: You forgot to cast `number` to a float in `min(number,minimal)`. Same problem for the line with `max`.

Comment: You are not type-casting the number to `float` in your `else` block

Answer (score 1):

In your function calls `min(number,minimal)` and `max(number,maximum)`, you aren't casting `number` to a float. This must be done as `minimal` and `maximum` are float types.

Try replacing the parameter `number` with `float(number)`, like so:

```
minimal=min(float(number),minimal)
maximum=max(float(number),maximum)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This solved the issue. I had thought about this and so had added the typecasting in if condition and assumed that as if block will be always implemented prior to else block, minimal and maximum would already be casted to float. I still didnt understand though why it worked for first few iterations (without float(number)in else block I mean).

Answer (score 0):

Below code works. Please see the differences:

```
count= 0
sum=0
average=0
minimal=None
maximum=None
while True:
    number=raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        if (number=='done'):
            break
        else:
            count=count+1
            sum=sum+float(number)
            if minimal==None:
                minimal=float(number)
                maximum=float(number)
            else:
                minimal=min(float(number),minimal)
                maximum=max(float(number),maximum)
                print maximum
                print minimal
            average=sum/count
            #print ("Calc done")
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")
print("Count: %d, Sum=%d and Average=%d" %(count,sum,average))
print("smallest number is %d" %minimal)
print("largest number is %0.2f" %float(maximum))
```

Comment: It's generally better to quickly explain what the differences are.